# parent process kills child process, even though detached is set to true

Tags: node.js, macos, process

I am really confused by this and have been struggling to find a solution for months. I am on OSX.

I hear that using child_process.spawn with the detached option set to true, will start the child process as a leader of a new process group and if the parent exits, the child process may continue running. However, I never witnessed any evidence of this.

https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html

For example:

```
const n = cp.spawn('node', ['watch-transpile.js'], {
    detached: true,
    stdio: ['ignore']
});
```

the above is executed by the parent, and if we run `$ ps aux | grep node`

we get:

```
Olegzandr        2546   0.0  0.2  3048544  19564   ??  Ss   11:29PM   0:00.09 node lib/transpile/watch-transpile.js

Olegzandr        2541   0.0  0.7  3115684  60216 s000  S+   11:29PM   0:01.47 node index -t -a -w
```

But when I kill the parent with control-c, the child process dies as well as the parent.

How can I truly create a background process that is independent of the parent process with node? this is killing me!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aha! Of course. Those stupid Node docs!

This works.

```
        const n = cp.spawn('node', ['lib/transpile/watch-transpile.js'], {
            detached: true,
            stdio: ['ignore', 'ignore', 'ignore']
        });
```

You explicitly ignore each stdio stream, not just using 'ignore' once; the docs don't mention this directly, but it makes sense given that the stdio property is an array.

See this issue on Github: https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/7269#issuecomment-225698625

Answer (score 2):

Try including the [**`child.unref()`**](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_options_detached) method.

> By default, the parent will wait for the detached child to exit. To
>   prevent the parent from waiting for a given child, use the
>   **child.unref()** method. Doing so will cause the parent's event loop to
>   not include the child in its reference count, allowing the parent to
>   exit independently of the child, unless there is an established IPC
>   channel between the child and parent.
>
> When using the detached option to start a long-running process, the
>   process will not stay running in the background after the parent exits
>   unless it is provided with a stdio configuration that is not connected
>   to the parent. If the parent's stdio is inherited, the child will
>   remain attached to the controlling terminal.
>
> Example of a long-running process, by detaching and also ignoring its
>   parent stdio file descriptors, in order to ignore the parent's
>   termination:

**Example:**

```
const n = cp.spawn('node', ['watch-transpile.js'], {
    detached: true,
    stdio: ['ignore']
}).unref();
```

**Examples** (*from the documentation*):

```
const spawn = require('child_process').spawn;

const child = spawn(process.argv[0], ['child_program.js'], {
  detached: true,
  stdio: ['ignore']
});

child.unref();
```

Alternatively one can redirect the child process' output into files:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
const out = fs.openSync('./out.log', 'a');
const err = fs.openSync('./out.log', 'a');

const child = spawn('prg', [], {
 detached: true,
 stdio: [ 'ignore', out, err ]
});

child.unref();
```

Comment: Just added an answer, it works. child.unref() solves the inverse of the problem at hand. I need to prevent the child from exiting when the parent exits. child.unref() allows the parent to the exit even if the child hasn't. perfect inverse :)